# setting up class path in environment variable

Tags: java, class

can we set a  user defined class path in environment variable without affecting the library class path if yes,then how can we do it? 
This would be really helpful.

Comment: Define "library class path". What are you trying to achieve? Why not pass the appropriate -classpath option to each of your programs?

Comment: just trying to learn things,nothing more than that!!!

Comment: Then do what I suggest. Forget about global environment variables. Use the -classpath optionand pass the appropriate classpath to each of your Java programs.